# How to use HDD hard disk (/dev/sda2) as a "Data" folder?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

My XPS desktop has 1 TB M.2 PCle NVMe SSD + 2TB 7200RPM 3.5" SATA HDD hard disks. And I just installed the Ubuntu 18.04 on my SSD harddisk. and it's my first time to use Linux system

When I look at my "Disks" Utility, I saw the SSD used as Linux LVM, and HDD is Linux Filesystem (Ext 4 -- mounted at /media/username/UUID number).
[Files GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcbWB.png)

I am wondering if I can link it as another large "Data" folder just like "Desktop" or "Document" shown in "Files"?

Currently, when I type "ls" in the terminal, it shows:
Desktop Download Music Public Videos Documents Pictures Templates

what I can do to show a "Data" folder which links to 2TB HDD hard disk (/dev/sda2)?

and when I want to access it in the terminal, the name is too long, something like:

`username@username-XPS-8930:~$ cd /media/username/4c86ba4b-5246-4934-bc9c-eabb85e44c76`

That's why I am wondering if I can access it through

`username@username-XPS-8930:~$ cd Data`

Comment: The HDD should appear in the left panel of the file manager. There is usually no need to do any linking. It is unclear if access it from the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever pic attached, I have to access it from "other location', while I am wondering if I can directly see it in the left panel

Comment: Is there some reason for LVM on SSD, but then not on HDD. LVM is more for advanced users, but if you must have encryption, you have to use LVM. To share data: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk